# How can I confirm which custom rule sets are being enforced by ESLint?

Tags: wordpress, eslint

I have ESLint installed, and I have installed a custom rule set, in the form of an ESLint plugin ([this plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@wordpress/eslint-plugin)).  Is there a surefire way I can confirm that I have correctly installed this custom ruleset, that ESLint recognizes the custom rule set, and will enforce those custom rules in future linting?  Right now, when I lint, ESLint displays infractions ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rD1xX.jpg)).  But those don't appear to be from my custom rule set.  I say that because if I right click on an infraction, and open the documentation on the rule, it opens the rule as described on the ESLint website.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From [this post](https://old.reddit.com/r/learnjavascript/comments/gqzcwh/eslint_how_can_i_confirm_which_custom_rule_sets/), I learned that one thing I can do is execute

`npx eslint --print-config file.js`

file.js can be any JS file.  I think it might not even need to exist (although I didn't test that).  The output will be a JSON object ([example](https://pastebin.com/X0Lp0fY8)).  One of the properties will be `plugins`.  Ensure that the `@wordpress` plugin is one of the values.  But that doesn't ensure the rules from the `@wordpress` rule set are being enforced.  To confirm that, look for another property in the object:  `rules`.  If there are rules prefixed with `@wordpress`, I believe this is a smoking gun indicating those rules are being enforced by ESLint.